# Create CSV or PDF files without saving it to disc and stream it to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: node.js, csv, amazon-s3, filestream, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have to create 2 files 1. `PDF` and 2. `CSV`, Both should be generated on a successful result.

I can generate `PDF` from `HTML` template using [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) package, I can create file stream without actually saving the file to disk, then `stream` the file using [streaming-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streaming-s3) package.

My problem starts with `CSV` files.

Curerently I'm creating a `CSV` file on the disk,

```
let testCsvData = ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3", ..., "Line n"];
const testCSV = path.join('./test.csv');
fs.writeFileSync(testCSV, testCsvData.join(os.EOL));
```

Then `createReadStream` and get the file stream to push.

```
let testStream = fs.createReadStream('./test.csv');
```

I don't want to save the `CSV` file to the disk and then get the file stream. Thats simply waste of space right!
Is there any way that I can directly get the file stream without saving it?